# MediaWiki Edit Rest API - invalid CSRF token error

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I am using [MediaWiki Rest API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit) to make an edit on a wiki with javascript code. I am able to extract login token, successfully login and retrieve an edit token as well. But, in the final step, while calling edit API, I get 'invalid CSRF token' error. Although I am handling cookies, it seems like, between login and extracting edit token, I am missing a step. Any helpful pointers would be much appreciated! ([link to my javascript code snippet](https://github.com/srish/mw_api_edit/blob/master/editing-with-js.js))

Comment: Would you show the relevant parts of your code in your question itself? We discourage file lockers, since if a link breaks we have to repair or delete a question, which creates new work for volunteers.

Comment: When I wrote a [node.js bot](https://github.com/toollabs/commons-maintenance-bot/blob/master/js/daily.js#L47) and running it at WIkimedia Labs, I encountered issues with the Wikimedia cluster not replicating the tokens between the request that creates it and the request that makes use of the token, i.e. one server created the token, returned it to my client and when I made the next request without any timeout, another server said "invalid token". Waiting a second solved the problem. But this was 4 years ago.

Comment: Chances are you are not handling sessions (ie. session cookies) correctly. Don't try to do it by hand, it's non-trivial. Just make the request library behave like a browser wrt cookies, pretty much all such libraries have an easy way of doing it.

Comment: FWIW, action=edit is part of the action API. The [REST API](https://www.mediawiki.org/api/rest_v1/) is a different thing.